# How can I make my UISwitch call method (I'm using theos)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiswitch, theos

I want a UISwitch to appear in CKTranscriptConversationController within the Messages.app (MobileSMS.app) and call the method forceMMS from the class CKConversation. It compiles fine, but when I launch the messages.app it crashes. Any ideas?

As soon as I launch the Messages.app it crashes, what i am trying to call is http://ghostbin.com/paste/3upv6 when the switch is turned on, and return FALSE; when the switch is off. I was able to make the actual switch show without the method but as soon as i put it in the code it crashes the app immediately.

Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKConversation.h>

@interface CKTranscriptCollectionViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *mySwitch;
@end

%hook CKTranscriptCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    %orig;
    self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mySwitch];
}   

-(BOOL)forceMMS {
    if ([self.mySwitch isOn]){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
}       

%end
```

Comment: paste crash message also

Comment: It compiles perfectly for me, but app crashes

Comment: @raki i don't have a crash message I'm using theos

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is call a method when the switch is toggled, add a *target* to the switch:

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethodHere:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then implement your method to take the switch as a parameter so you can get the state when it is toggled:

```
- (void)yourMethodHere:(UISwitch *)theSwitch {
    NSLog(@"The switch is %@.", theSwitch.isOn ? @"on" : @"off");
}
```

Comment: I compiled this code and launched messages.app and it still crashed.

Comment: Well you're gonna need to provide some information because I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be. As I mentioned in another comment, I couldn't even get that code to compile.

Comment: Where does it crash? When does it crash? What is the stack trace? What is the exception?

Comment: ghostbin.com/paste/tnoyq I put what you said in the code and it compiles but still crashes the app, and yes i just simply want to call a method when the switch is pressed. thank you –  Brandon Salgado 58 secs ago   edit

Comment: Once again...Where does it crash? When does it crash? What is the stack trace? What is the exception?

Comment: as soon as I launch the Messages.app it crashes, what i am trying to call is https://ghostbin.com/paste/3upv6 when the switch is turned on, and return FALSE; when the switch is off. I was able  to make the actual switch show without the method but as soon as i out it in the code it crashes the app immediately.

Comment: I don't know what Messages.app is, and I don't have any experience with Theos. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: you know the messages app on the iPhone (MobileSMS.app)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

ViewDidload:

```
self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];
[self.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeInSwitch:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:self.mySwitch];

- (IBAction)changeInSwitch:(id)sender
{

if ([self forceMMS)
{
   NSLog(@"IN ON");
}
else
{
 NSLog(@"IN OFF");
 }

  }

 -(BOOL)forceMMS {
 if ([self.mySwitch isOn]){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
   }
```

Comment: but is that going to call this: http://ghostbin.com/paste/3upv6 when the switch is turned on?

Comment: Just want to call the method

Comment: this is the code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/ba6av this is the error from theos: https://ghostbin.com/paste/hzqoj